# How to apply to_datetime on pandas Dataframe column?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with `Timestamp` entries in one column, created from strings like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": pd.to_datetime("MARCH2016")})
```

Now I want to select from `df` based on month, cutting across years, by accessing the `.month` attribute of the `datetime` object. However, `to_datetime` actually created a `Timestamp` object from the string, and I can't seem to coerce it to `datetime`. The following works as expected:

```
type(df.x[0].to_datetime())  # gives datetime object
```

but using `apply` (which in my real life example of course I want to do given that I have more than one row) doesn't:

```
type(df.x.apply(pd.to_datetime)[0]) # returns Timestamp
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you expect but it should work fine `df['x'].dt.month`

Comment: I just didn't realize that `datetime` was an attribute of the `Timestamp` object - I though I can either create a `datetime` or a `Timestamp` object, and that I would need the `datetime` object to access the `month` attribute... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's a `TimeStamp` is irrelevant here, you can still access the `month` attribute using `.dt` accessor:

```
In [79]:
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [pd.to_datetime("MARCH2016")]})
df['x'].dt.month

Out[79]:
0    3
Name: x, dtype: int64
```